# Converting excel formula to javascript - Math.pow()?

Tags: javascript, excel

I have the following formula in Excel.

F14 = 100000

F15 = 10

F16 = 10

```
=(((1+F16)^(1/12)-1)*F14)/(1-((1+((1+F16)^(1/12)-1))^(-F15*12)))
```

This results in 1,297.75 which is correct. Simply trying to use the same formula in js gives a result of 8800, obviously wrong.

As I understand it, ^ should be replaced by Math.pow(A,B), correct? Even so, I'm having real trouble making this out correctly.

Could anybody help me out?

EDIT: Everything is good. The formula I posted was slightly different than the one in excel (don't know how i made that happen). Everything is good and makes sense now. Thanks everybody

Comment: Yep. `^` is for manipulating bits, `Math.pow` is for exponentiation. (In ES2016 the `**` operator also does exponentiation.)

Comment: no matter what, your result should be: `=(((1+F16)^(1/12)-1)*F14)/(1-((1+((1+F16)^(1/12)-1))^(-F15*12))) =(((1+10)^(1/12)-1)*100000)/(1-((1+((1+10)^(1/12)-1))^(-10*12))) =((11^(1/12)-1)*100000)/(1-((1+(11^(1/12)-1))^-120)) =(0.22118855031199*100000)/(1-(1.22118855031199^-120)) =22118.855031199/0.999999999961446 =~22118.8550320518`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Excel, I get the value of `22118,85503` and so does this

```js
var F14 = 100000,
    F15 = 10,
    F16 = 10; 

console.log(((Math.pow(1 + F16, 1 / 12) - 1) * F14) / (1 - (Math.pow(1 + (Math.pow(1 + F16, 1 / 12) - 1), -F15 * 12))));
```

Comment: Strange. What version of Excel do you run? Maybe the formula is somehow wrong itself, given the varied results? I get the expected result in openoffice and Google sheets as well, but Numbers gives me 23k

Comment: MS Office Professional Plus 2016

Comment: Thank you again. It turns out something was wrong with my formula (didn't match the one I posted. All is good now)